# Groupby in DataFrame with class objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let say I have two following objects which I use in DataFrame

```
 online_price = OnlinePrice(article_id=1,
                                   date=datetime.date(2020, 11, 5),
                                   min_sale_price=62.99,
                                   max_sale_price=83.94,
                                   avg_sale_price=83.74,
                                  median_sale_price=100.00)
 online_price_group = OnlinePriceGroup(title='Test OnlinePriceGroup',
                                              user_id=1,
                                              selection_group_id=1,
                                              periodic_task_id=1,
                                              min_price_multiplier=30,
                                              calculator_method=enums.OnlineGroupCalculatorMethod.USE_LOWEST_OF_RECOMMENDATION_AND_ONLINE_PRICE,
                                              status=enums.OnlineGroupStatus.ACTIVE,
                                              allow_higher_than_current_prices=enums.OnlineGroupUseHigherPriceThanCurrent.ALLOW)
```

I want to have groupby with 'status' for example dividing ACTIVE and INACTIVE.

[image: Code which I tried to execute]

Gives me back this error '<' not supported between instances of 'OnlinePriceGroup' and 'OnlinePriceGroup'

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs since you are using custom defined classes where you have not defined how to compare two instances of the class with eachother. How do you determine whether group 1 is larger than group 2? That logic needs to be added first

A minimum example of this can be seen below

```py
class GroupClass:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.val > other.val

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.val >= other.val
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.val == other.val
```

With the above, you would be able to run

```py
print(GroupClass(2) > GroupClass(3))
print(GroupClass(2) >= GroupClass(3))
print(GroupClass(2) == GroupClass(3))
```